# Jquery-tab abnormally block my div

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I am facing the problem that the jquery-tab block my Main menu class="oe_wrapper" that is located on the nav bar id="NavBar". I want the oe_menu can overlay the tabs. Is there any problem with this code? thanks in advance.

http://jsfiddle.net/Sp7Mk/

mark-up:

```
<div id="NavBar" style="width: 500px; height: 100px; background-color: blue;">
  <div class="oe_wrapper" style="background-color: red;">
                <ul id="oe_menu" class="oe_menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="">Main Menu</a>
                        <div>
                            <ul>
                                <li class="oe_heading">
                                    My Account
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Account Information</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul>
                                <li class="oe_heading">
                                    Forms
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">F-1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">F-2</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
</div>

<div id="searchTab">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tabsAddll">Address</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabsOther">Other</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabsDis">Disabled</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="tabsAddll">
                <p>Address</p>
            </div>
            <div id="tabsOther">
                <p>Other</p>
            </div>
        <div id="tabsDis">
                <p>Disabled</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $( "#searchTab" ).tabs({ disabled: [ 2 ] });
    });
```

css:

```
*{ margin: 0 auto;}
body {
    background:#000000; 
}
ul.oe_menu{
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    clear:both;
   left: -400px;
}
ul.oe_menu > li{
    padding-bottom:2px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
ul.oe_menu > li > a{
    display:block;
    background-color:#717171;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:12px;
    /* a link */
    width:90px;
    height:16px;
    padding:1.3px;
    margin:1px;
    text-shadow:0px 0px 1px #000;
    /*opacity:0.8;*/
    text-align: center !important;
}
ul.oe_menu > li > a:hover,
ul.oe_menu > li.selected > a{
    background:#fff;
    color:#101010;
    opacity:1.0;
}
.oe_wrapper ul.hovered > li > a{
    background:#fff;
    text-shadow:0px 0px 1px #FFF;
}
ul.oe_menu div{
    position:absolute;
    left:1px;
    background:#fff;
    width:668px;
    padding:30px;
}
ul.oe_menu div ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#222;
    padding:2px 2px 2px 4px;
    margin:2px;
    display:block;
    font-size:12px;
}
ul.oe_menu div ul.oe_full{
    width:100%;
}
ul.oe_menu div ul li a:hover{
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
}
ul.oe_menu li ul{
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    width: 150px;
    margin-right:10px;
    text-align: left;
}
li.oe_heading{
    color:#aaa;
    font-size:16px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    padding-bottom:6px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
<div id="NavBar" style="width: 500px; height: 100px; background-color: blue;">
```

You are explicitly declaring a height for the navbar of 100px, so after 100px it's space in the DOM ends and the next element starts to render. Try changing the height to 175px, for me that put it right underneath your other menu.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I will set that height to be smaller (25px) because this is a navigation bar that I will put my menu button there.

Comment: So I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish then...You want the secondary menu (jquery UI menu) to not overlay the "main menu" but be only 25px below it? It will certainly always block the text behind it if it is 25px below the first menu.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to explain the "Main Menu" button. There is a grey button "Main Menu" on top. The true is, when the mouse is over on the "Main menu" button, the "oe_menu" will be populated. After the mouse leave the "Main Menu", the oe_menu will disappear.

Comment: So what do you want the jquery-ui menu to do while the "main menu" button is hovered over? how about when not hovered over?

Comment: Do you mean the mouse NOT hover over the "main menu"? Then the oe_menu will not be shown(display: none;) For easily displaying the oe_menu will be blocked by jquery-tab, I have set the oe_menu always displayed.

Comment: So you still aren't completely clear, when the "main menu" button is not hovered over and the oe-menu disappears, do you want the jquery-ui menu to accordion up and then when you hover on "main menu" and oe-menu content shows to accordion down, or what specific behavior do you want and where exactly do you want elements to be during the effects? Please be specific in exactly how your fiddle is wrong, Thanks! :D

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22426/discussion-between-drcord-and-user1439709)